# Finding the supremum of this set and determine if it is a maximum

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

$F = \{1-2^{-n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

In my first year analysis class we take it in two steps.

1) $(1-2^{-n})<m, \ \forall \,n\in \mathbb{N}$, so $m$ is a supremum of F.

2) Let $\epsilon>0$. We want to find $x\in F$ such that $x>1-\epsilon$.

The first section was not difficult, I found it to be $1$. But when I do the algebra for the second step I run into difficulty near the end, here are the steps I've taken so far;

$1-2^{-n}>1-\epsilon$

$-\frac{1}{2^{n}}>-\epsilon$

$\frac{1}{2^{n}}<\epsilon$

$2^{n}>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$

And then I can't find a way to get $n$ on its own without taking the log of both sides. We haven't done anything that advanced in these examples, so I think there must be something easier that I'm missing.

Comment: Karl.$(1+1)^n\ge 1+n\cdot 1,$ use Binomial expansion.

Comment: well the question just becomes "given a real positive number epsilon, is there a natural number n such that $2^n > 1/\epsilon$ ?.

Comment: You can find exactly who the minimum n must be by taking logarithms, but the existence of such an n can just be established by the fact that $2^n$ diverges

Comment: determining if it's a maximum should be trivial

Comment: Since $\frac1{2^n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, there exist $N\in \Bbb N$ such that, for all $n>N$, $$\frac1{2^n}<\epsilon$$.

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio Our final step in the lecture examples usually have n on it's own and $\epsilon$ on the other side of the inequality being manipulated in some way. i.e.: $n>\log_{2}(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$, which I know leaves me with $n>-\log_{2}({\epsilon})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the supremum is 1.  All I can say is, go ahead and take the logarithm.  You say 
"we haven't done anything that advanced" but you clearly know what a logarithm is so there is no reason not to use it.